# Open Graph Protocol via HTTP response headers

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to provide [Open Graph Protocol (OGP)](https://ogp.me/) metadata in HTTP response headers (serialized or individually) instead of the the current HTTP response body implementation with HTML `<meta>` tags?

I understand the reasoning of avoiding content-related data in HTTP headers, but do any OGP clients read/parse OGP response header metadata instead? This could be very useful for HEAD requests for media file URLs (*.mp4, *.mkv, *.opus, etc) without requiring responses to be `Content-Type: text/html`.

Comment: To my knowledge, no major network supports that. Facebook has the ability to "point" from one HTML document to a different URL to fetch the meta data from there (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/optimizing), but that's it. Nothing in terms of HTTP headers.

Comment: _"This could be very useful for HEAD requests for media file URLs (*.mp4, *.mkv, *.opus, etc) without requiring responses to be Content-Type: text/html."_ - not sure I get the point here; you would not respond to GET request for a video file with an HTML response either? Or are you asking in terms of _sharing_ the URL to a plain video file directly - instead of an HTML document, that will embed said video? [...]

Comment: [...] I don't think Facebook or other networks would _want_ links to "plain" files so much to begin with. (Can't get people to inject a tracking pixel into those, so how would they keep on sniffing on what their users are doing then, haha.)

Comment: You could try and test if Facebook accepts the `<link rel="opengraph" href="{DESTINATION_URL}"/>` from that pointer method, as a [`Link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link) HTTP header instead ... But I really rather doubt it will work, if they had implemented that as an alternative, I think it would be mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

> but do any OGP clients read/parse OGP response header metadata instead?

To my knowledge, no major network supports that. Facebook has the ability to "point" from one HTML document to a different URL to fetch the meta data from there (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/optimizing), but that's it. Nothing in terms of HTTP headers.

> This could be very useful for HEAD requests for media file URLs (*.mp4, *.mkv, *.opus, etc) without requiring responses to be Content-Type: text/html.

Not sure I get the point here; you would not respond to a GET request for a video file with an HTML response either? Or are you asking in terms of sharing the URL to a plain video file directly - instead of an HTML document, that will embed said video? I don't think Facebook or other networks would want links to "plain" files so much to begin with. (Can't get people to inject a tracking pixel into those, so how would they keep on sniffing on what their users are doing then, haha.) –

You could try and test if Facebook accepts the `<link rel="opengraph" href="{DESTINATION_URL}"/>` from that pointer method, as a [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link) HTTP header instead ... But I really rather doubt it will work, if they had implemented that as an alternative, I think it would be mentioned in the docs.